# Function to assign colours (in R plot for bivariate data)

Tags: r, function, plot, colors

I need a function that assigns colours in a plot. I have 244 data points to plot and I want data points 1-86 to be `"coral1"`, points 87-160 to be  `"steelblue2"`, and points 161-244 to be `"steelblue4"`.

In addition, I use a sunflowerplot from the `graphics`package that can only plot bivariate data, so my data points have one x- and one y-value that are given as vectors:

```
    sunflowerplot(x, y)
```

The colour is a third info that apparently cannot be taken from the data.frame(`typmed5`) in this case - adding `data=typmed5` doesn't work, so I cannot use a function that uses additional info from the df (i.e. it seems like the function cannot look like this:

```
    cols <- character(nrow(typmed5))
    cols[typmed5[,1] == "meto"] <- "coral1"         
    cols[typmed5[,1] == "metT"] <- "steelblue2"     
    cols[typmed5[,1] == "meop"] <- "steelblue4"
```

The df looks like this (nrow=244):

```
        Typ bek_Med vst_Med verw_Med woe_Med color2
     1 meto       2       3        2       5 coral1
     2 meto       3       3        2       5 coral1
     3 meto       3       3        3       4 coral1
     4 meto       3       3        3       4 coral1
     5 meto       2       3        3       3 coral1
     6 meto       2       3        3       4 coral1
```

My columns 2 through 5 are supposed to be the x- and y-vectors, so I need several plots, so it would be good to have a generalizable colour function.
Many thanks

Comment: Yeah, there are quite a few duplicates. I thought it would just plot each and every data point with the corresponding color while each data point = 1 petal. So, `c(1, 3, "meto")` would give one coral1-colored petal, `c(1, 3, "metT")`gives a steelblue2-colored one. But if by " What colors is the points?" you mean the center of the petals (?), you define those separately. I did find a non-elegant solution: Subsetting the df acc. to type, defining one color for each subset, then plot 3 plots on top each other. That works quite well.

Answer (score 0):

[edited] `sunflowerplot(x, y)` does (1) sort (x has priority), (2) treat non flower data (not duplicated data), (3) treat flower data. So, you can get suitable colors after handling your data in the same way.

```
  ## example data
typmed5 <- cbind(iris[,c(5,1:4)], rep(c("coral1", "steelblue2", "steelblue4"), each=50))
names(typmed5) <- c("Typ", "bek_Med", "vst_Med", "verw_Med", "woe_Med", "color2")
typmed5[,-c(1, 6)] <- round(typmed5[,-c(1, 6)])
typmed5$color2 <- as.character(typmed5$color2)


  ## (1) sort by x and y, (2) keep only flower data (duplicated data), (3) get colors
petal.func <- function(x, y, df) {
  temp <- df[order(df[,x], df[,y]),]
  colv <- temp[duplicated(temp[,c(x, y)]) | duplicated(temp[,c(x, y)], fromLast=T),]$color2
  return(as.character(colv))
}

  ## use
col.v <- petal.func("bek_Med", "vst_Med", typmed5)

with(typmed5, sunflowerplot(bek_Med, vst_Med, seg.col = col.v))
legend("bottomright", levels(typmed5$Typ), lty=1, col=c("coral1", "steelblue2", "steelblue4"), bty="n")

  ## to check
with(typmed5, table(Typ, bek_Med, vst_Med))[,,1] # vst_Med = 2 data
#             bek_Med
# Typ          4 5 6 7 8
#   setosa     1 0 0 0 0
#   versicolor 0 4 9 0 0
#   virginica  0 1 3 1 0
```

[image]